# Is it possible to simply compile an Emma instrumented APK using Android build.xml and not run any tests

Tags: android

I know of

```
ant coverage
```

However that does a few things, it compiles with emma instrumentation, installs, and runs the test apk. I don't want it to run the test suite through ant with coverage because I need to run it with some extra hooks, and I don't want to run the large test suite twice. So far I have tried this

**Target_Project/build.properties**

```
emma.enabled=true
```

**Test_Project/build.properties**

```
emma.enabled=true
```

Then in in a shell I execute this.

```
Target_Project$ ant debug
Target_Project$ adb install bin/Target_Project-debug.apk
Target_Project$ cd ../Test_Project/
Test_Project$ ant debug
Test_Project$ adb install bin/Test_Project-debug.apk
Test_Project$ adb shell am instrument -e coverage true -e coverageFile /sdcard/myFile.ec -w com.my_app.testproject/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

The response is

```
Error: Failed to generate emma coverage. Is emma jar on classpath?
```

So is there a trick to getting the apk to build with the emma libs? I tried invoking the targets created in the sdk xml templates but they are "private." Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for anyone interested. The SDK documentation is completely busted (surprising I know). Basically you have to do this,

take the base build.xml generated by android create-project and change the tag

```
<setup/>
```

and change it to

```
<setup import="false"/>
```

Now the documentation will tell you to copy from SDK/platform-/templates/android_rules.xml and place that into your build.xml ...
**THIS IS WRONG** and horribly unmaintained. This rules file isn't used by anything. What is used are the rules inside of SDK/tools/ant/. Grab the appropriate file for your type of project (library for a library project, test for a test project, or vanilla for a regualr project) with the latest _r and
copy the contents of it's root node into your build.xml. Insert it after the setup tag. If you don't use the files inside the ant directory, you will not be able to compile project libraries through the ant script. I was so glad they maintained documentation on how to do this.

Now you can change whatever you like in the build file to match your build needs. In which case I just made install-helper call my wrapper around adb which returns interpreted resultcodes.

Comment: I can sense your frustration in this :) However, I think you're being too hard on the Android team.  If you were to rebuild your build.xml file via `android update project .` (when there is no build.xml file in your project), you'd see that the outdated documentation you're referring to has actually been updated to refer to the current filenames.  If you had generated your build.xml from an older SDK version, it would probably reference older files that have since been renamed.  `android update project` won't modify build.xml if it doesn't have to, hence the outdated documentation.

Comment: At the time this question was written this was the result of android update project :( Hence my frustration. I had to pick it apart by hand.

Answer (score -1):

// coverage.py

development\testrunner\coverage.py

def TestDeviceCoverageSupport(adb):
  """Check if device has support for generating code coverage metrics.

This tries to dump emma help information on device, a response containing
  help information will indicate that emma is already on system class path.

Returns:
    True if device can support code coverage. False otherwise.
  """
  try:
    output = adb.SendShellCommand("exec app_process / emma -h")

```
if output.find('emma usage:') == 0:
  return True
```

except errors.AbortError:
    pass
  return False

> adb shell exec app_process / eamm -h

build core images
http://duykham.blogspot.com/2009/09/how-to-get-emma-code-coverage-of.html