# Android - generate coverage with emma (without ant)

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb, code-coverage, emma

After running `ant clean emma debug` and installing the generated apk file on my emulator, I am running the following command to run my unit tests:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e package org.company.projectname.test.unit -e coverage true \
-e coverageFile ProjectNameTest/bin/coverage.xml org.company.projectname.tests/com.neenbedankt.android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner'
```

The InstrumentationTestRunner I am using is a subclass of `android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner`.

When I run this command, all the tests pass, but then no coverage is generated and I get the error:
`Error: Failed to generate emma coverage.  Is emma jar on classpath?`

I am not looking for a solution that uses `ant test`, unless that solution can address the reason I' not using it, which is that I wanted to be able to specify a package within `org.company.projectname.test` to test (in this case the `unit` package).

Comment: why won't you just edit your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558226/android-generate-emma-coverage-xml-file-via-command-line

Comment: In retrospect, maybe I should have.  I'd honestly prefer to just delete that question.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
ant instrument
ant emma installi test
```

Edit:
If you do not want to use Ant you have to build the instrumented apk manually, check $ANDROID_HOME/tools/ant/build.xml for more info and make sure emma.jar is under libs of your test project.

Answer (score 0):

Try :
ant all clean emma debug install test

and also please check http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21640 , it seems like this issue is fixed latest commit

Comment: and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4073681/is-it-possible-to-simply-compile-an-emma-instrumented-apk-using-android-build-xm